# Debug Node application in CF

Tags: node.js, debugging, cloud-foundry

We are using Diego version  2.80 and I'm trying to debug **node.js** application...in this URL there is place which you should install node inspector and expose debug port , my question is there a **shorter way** to do it ?  maybe without having the need to download the node inspector ...

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using? Starting around 6.4.0 you can attach Chrome DevTools without having to install node-inspector.

Comment: @opiethehokie - Thanks so could you please write the steps as answer ( I will use the lateset version of node ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this guide which solved the issue
https://codeburst.io/an-easy-way-to-debug-node-js-apps-in-cloud-foundry-22f559d44516

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix provides documentation that will show you the options of how to manage and debug Liberty and Node.js apps:

[Managing Liberty and Node.js apps](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_mng.html)

I would recommend reading this documentation to see what options you want to utilize. Please note some of the options work for both Liberty and Node.js, but others are specific to each runtime.

There is even detailed information regarding the inspector you mention above, but the steps you need to take are dependent on your Node version:

[Node.js inspector](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_mng.html#inspector)

Comment: Thanks but this is coupled to bluemix , there is more generic one  ? which is not platform independent ?

Comment: @RaynD: I saw the ibm-bluemix tag included in your question and that is why I supplied you with an answer that included the instructions on Bluemix. Are you using a standalone Node.js application, that is not hosted on Bluemix?

Comment: Yes I use both and for this question I need use generic CF supplier

Comment: I am going to remove the ibm-bluemix tag and I will try to supply an answer for generic CF

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest Node.js v6:

1. in your package.json change your app's start command from something like `node app.js` to `node --inspect app.js`
2. push your app
3. create a SSH tunnel so you can remotely access the debug port which by default is 9229: `cf ssh -N -T -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 <appName>`
4. get your chrome-devtools URL from `cf logs <appName> --recent` and browse to it (it will take a few seconds to load)

Comment: Thanks this is what I need but I try it and I got error when pushing the application, If I put the engine explicit in the package json   "engines": {
    "node": "6.4.0"
  }  I got error ailed to compile droplet Exit status 223
 even If I push the application with the latest buildpack  cf push -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack

Comment: I try with engine 6.10.3 and I dont get error during push but when I do cf logs myapp --recent I got this: 2017-05-25T10:07:20.94+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Debugger listening on 0.0.0.0:5858
2017-05-25T10:07:21.11+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Application is listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: when i do cf ssh -N -T -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 myApp I got error connect to 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: ssh: rejected: connect failed (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9229: getsockopt: connection refused)
any idea what could be the issue ?

Comment: I think 5858 was the old node-inspector debug port. Maybe your previous debug attempts are still having an effect here?

Comment: There is something that you think that I should do to check it ?